# Recently had a slow-speed crash - wondering if I should replace my helmet

Tags: helmets, crash

recently I got into a slow speed crash that ended up with me scuffing into a wall and the pavement. Initially I didn't feel any head-crash but after finishing my ride I noticed that my helmet was scuffed as well as a fine line on the same side of my head where I think the helmet pushed into my skin (just a mark no wound).

I read that light scuff marks without impact shouldn't matter, but since I have that mark I imagine there was "some" impact to it.

Hence I'm wondering should I be replacing this helmet? (my gutt says yes, since I only have one head)

[image]

Comment: While the fact that the helmet left a mark on your head is evidence of a replacement-worthy impact, do you see any crushed foam beneath the scuffed zone? Just out of interest.

Comment: No crushed foam whatsoever, I checked both the middle piece as well as the foam underneath the helmet, but no indication of crushing.

Comment: Have you checked that the line on the side of your head isn't just something you get every time you wear the helmet but never looked for before?

Comment: Ultimately it comes down to your tolerance for risk, and your disposable income.  Only you can make the decision.   I might have a personal opinion if it were my head, which may be higher or lower than for someone else.

Comment: Yea already decided Ill replace it

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is generally recommended to inspect a helmet and replace if necessary after an impact.

Inspection involves pressing on the outside shell looking for areas where the foam is compressed and taking out the padding from the inside to look for signs of compression or cracks.  Some good advice can be found at the following links:
https://helmets.org/inspection.htm

https://www.bikeradar.com/features/how-to-inspect-and-care-for-your-helmet/

Most helmet manufacturers offer some form of crash replacement scheme.  In the case of your Lazer helmet (in the UK) this can be found here: https://www.lazersport.com/uk/crash-replacement-program

Answer (score 2):

The rules are: helmet that took a hit during the crash [to be replaced](https://helmets.org/replace.htm). As seen from the scratch, this helmet have done. It does not matter if it still looks like new or better than new.

It has been a good helmet and served you really well if you do not feel anything after the crash (this is a known common observation, not a joke).  Beyond doubt, buy another like this.

Comment: We really can't say much about how well the helmet served the OP, based on the information. It's also possible that it was barely an impact at all and only the wall's chalky material left the marks on the helmet, or that the OP was too distracted by pain in e.g. the arm and post-crash shakiness to notice about the head.

Comment: To have a scratch like this on your head, it would be something.

Comment: @nightrider My body has healed back worse bruises than what those scratches indicate. They were on different parts of the body though. But the point is, no matter how gruesome an abrasive bruise may look, unless there was enough force involved to damage the bones/tendons/muscles/brains behind the skin, it's just a bruise and not worth fretting over. We cannot judge from the image how much force was behind those scratches, so the helmet *may* only have prevented a bruise, which would not be what the helmet is intended to do. It exists for saving you from things much, much worse than that.